# Get method in constructor

Tags: java, constructor

Ok, here is then whole code (In different language, but..):

```
public class BackPropagation {
    public double[][] targeti;
    public double[][] ulazi;
    public int brSlojeva;
    Sloj[] slojevi;
    public double minErr;
    public double brzinaObucavanja;
    public int maxBrEpoha;


    BackPropagation(double[][] zadatiTargeti, double[][] zadatiUlazi, double zadataGreska, double zadataBrzinaObucavanja,int[] brNeuronaPoSlojevima,String[] zadateFcjeAktivacije, int zadatBrEpoha)
    {
        if((targeti.length>=0)&&(ulazi.length>=0)&&(ulazi.length==targeti.length)){
            targeti = new double[zadatiTargeti.length][zadatiTargeti[0].length];
            for(int i=0;i<targeti.length;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<targeti[0].length;j++)
                    targeti[i][j] = zadatiTargeti[i][j];
            ulazi = new double[zadatiUlazi.length][zadatiUlazi[0].length];
            for(int i=0;i<ulazi.length;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<ulazi[0].length;j++)
                    ulazi[i][j] = zadatiUlazi[i][j];
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Broj treninga i broj ulaza mora biti jednak, i veci od nule!");     
        if(brNeuronaPoSlojevima.length>0){
            brSlojeva = brNeuronaPoSlojevima.length;
            slojevi = new Sloj[brNeuronaPoSlojevima.length];
            slojevi[0] = new Sloj(zadatiUlazi[0].length,brNeuronaPoSlojevima[0],zadateFcjeAktivacije[0]);
        for(int i=1;i<brNeuronaPoSlojevima.length;i++)
            slojevi[i] = new Sloj(brNeuronaPoSlojevima[i-1],brNeuronaPoSlojevima[i],zadateFcjeAktivacije[i]);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Mora postojati bar jedan sloj! Unesite vrednost vecu od nule.");        
        brzinaObucavanja = zadataBrzinaObucavanja;
        minErr = zadataGreska;
        maxBrEpoha = zadatBrEpoha;
        public int getBrSlojeva (int[] brNeuronaPoSlojevima){
            return brNeuronaPoSlojevima.length;
        }   
    }


    public void Treniraj()
    {
        int brEpoha=0;
        double ukupnaGreska;
        do{
            ukupnaGreska =0;
            for(int i=0;i<ulazi.length;i++)
            {
                slojevi[0].setUlazi(ulazi[i]);

                RacunanjeIzlazaSlojeva();
                for(int j=0;j<slojevi[brSlojeva-1].neuroni.length;j++)
                    ukupnaGreska+=Math.pow(targeti[i][j]-slojevi[brSlojeva-1].neuroni[j].izlaz, 2); // treba da pise slojevi od brSlojeva-1 jer nam trebaju izlazi iz neuronske mreze, a oni su u poslednjem sloju

                RacunanjeDelteNeurona(i);

                AzuriranjeTezinaIBijasa();
            }
            brEpoha++;
            ukupnaGreska/=2;
        }while(brEpoha<maxBrEpoha && ukupnaGreska>minErr);
    }





    private void RacunanjeIzlazaSlojeva()
    {
        for(int i =0;i<brSlojeva;i++)
        {
            slojevi[i].IzracunajIzlazeNeurona();
            if(i<brSlojeva-1)
                slojevi[i+1].setUlazi(slojevi[i].VratiIzlazeSloja());
        }
    }

    private void RacunanjeDelteNeurona(int brTreninga)
    {
        double suma = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<slojevi[brSlojeva-1].neuroni.length;i++)
            slojevi[brSlojeva-1].neuroni[i].setSignalError((targeti[brTreninga][i]-slojevi[brSlojeva-1].neuroni[i].izlaz)*slojevi[brSlojeva-1].IzvodFcjeAktivacije(slojevi[brSlojeva-1].neuroni[i].izlaz));
        for(int i=brSlojeva-2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<slojevi[i].neuroni.length;j++)
            {
                suma = 0;
                for(int k=0;k<slojevi[i+1].neuroni.length;k++)
                {
                    suma += slojevi[i+1].neuroni[k].getSignalError()*slojevi[i+1].neuroni[k].tezine[j];
                }
                slojevi[i].neuroni[j].setSignalError(suma*slojevi[i].IzvodFcjeAktivacije(slojevi[i].neuroni[j].izlaz));
            }
        }


    }

    private void AzuriranjeTezinaIBijasa()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<slojevi.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<slojevi[i].neuroni.length;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<slojevi[i].getUlazi().length;k++)
                    slojevi[i].neuroni[j].tezine[k] = slojevi[i].neuroni[j].tezine[k] + brzinaObucavanja*slojevi[i].neuroni[j].getSignalError()*slojevi[i].getUlazi()[k];
                slojevi[i].neuroni[j].setBijas(slojevi[i].neuroni[j].getBijas() + brzinaObucavanja * slojevi[i].neuroni[j].getSignalError());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

THis is what im suppose to get rid of `public int brSlojeva;`
As u can see, this brSlojeva is used everywhere out of constructor, and the question is, how to get rid of it, but use the value of `brNeuronaPoSlojevima` if its  visible only in constructor..

Comment: Do you have a `int[] numNeuronsPerLayer` field in your class?

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question with a complete code sample. Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: It is really complicated code (Neural Networks), and variables arent in english, would take a lot of time to reconstruct that code in minimal example, and i dont have that time. Kinda in rush. I can email code to u, if u think u have enough time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough time. Anyway, the errors posted here cannot be replicated by your given code. It would be better if you post the relevant code.

Comment: No. But that is the point, i have numLayers, as u see. And im asked to take it out, but to remain functionality of the code. If i do declare
numNeuronsPerLayer as u said, i didnt achive anything. Almost like i renamed numLayers.

Answer (score 1):

The design of this class seems questionable, and I don't know why the `numLayers` instance variable needs to be removed.

As for the compiler errors, your method needs to know what `numNeuronsPerLayer` is. Since it is not an instance variable, the only other option is to pass it in as a parameter, as with your constructor:

```
public int getNumLayers(int[] numNeuronsPerLayer) {
    return numNeuronsPerLayer.length;
}
```

And this method definition *cannot* exist within your constructor.

Also, this isn't a very helpful method, simply returning the length of an array. Any callers of this method would be better off accessing the `length` property of their array directly.

Comment: Alternatively `numNeuronsPerLayer` could be saved as a class variable. It depends on what the idea behind this class is.

Comment: @blalasaadri The OP _was_ saving that value to the `numLayers` instance variable, but for some reason was told to remove it.

Comment: The numLayers variable, yes. Not `numNeuronsPerLayer`. As I said, it very much depends on what should be done with the class.

Comment: While this makes the code compile, it gives such an odd design to have a method to retrieve the length of the array =\

Comment: And now I wonder why to propose such an answer which derives in poor design =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Hopefully the OP can understand why the compiler errors were occurring.

Comment: In fact, this code fix doesn't solve any of the problems stated by OP. We cannot even solve them since the given code doesn't provide any hint about those errors.

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right, then `brSlojeva` is length of `brNeuronaPoSlojevima`. 
In constructor you have `slojevi = new Sloj[brNeuronaPoSlojevima.length];` so it means, that `Sloj[] slojevi;` is the same length as `brNeuronaPoSlojevima`, therefore `public int brSlojeva;` has the same value as expression `slojevi.length`. Delete `brSlojeva` from fields, and replace it in methods by `slojevi.length`. That should work.

Also get rid of

```
public int getBrSlojeva (int[] brNeuronaPoSlojevima){
            return brNeuronaPoSlojevima.length;
        }
```

there is no such things like methods definition in constructors. I know what you was hoping for, but such things are simply impossible.

PS. in java methods name should start start with a lowercase letter.